# Issues Converting a Project to a Sublime/Mavensmate Project

Tags: sublimetext3

I am having issues with my Sublime and Mavensmate... I have only just recently started using it so I don't have a CLUE what to do with it. Would someone mind helping me?

```
[MAVENSMATE]: Calling mm_interface
[MAVENSMATE]: OPERATION: new_project_from_existing_directory
[MAVENSMATE]: {'params': {'directory': '/Users/tgentet-obrien/Dune'}}
[MAVENSMATE]: executing mm terminal call:
[MAVENSMATE]: /Applications/MavensMate.app/Contents/Resources/mm/mm --ui -o new_project_from_existing_directory -c SUBLIME_TEXT_3
[MAVENSMATE]: {"directory": "/Users/tgentet-obrien/Dune"}
[MAVENSMATE]: response from mm: {"body": "Could not load default MavensMate settings.", "stack_trace": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/Users/josephferraro/Development/Github/mm/tools/pyinstaller-dev/mm/build/pyi.darwin/mm/out00-PYZ.pyz/lib.request\", line 63, in execute\n  File \"/Users/josephferraro/Development/Github/mm/tools/pyinstaller-dev/mm/build/pyi.darwin/mm/out00-PYZ.pyz/lib.request\", line 54, in __setup_connection\n  File \"/Users/josephferraro/Development/Github/mm/tools/pyinstaller-dev/mm/build/pyi.darwin/mm/out00-PYZ.pyz/lib.connection\", line 34, in __init__\n  File \"/Users/josephferraro/Development/Github/mm/tools/pyinstaller-dev/mm/build/pyi.darwin/mm/out00-PYZ.pyz/lib.connection\", line 169, in get_plugin_client_settings\nMMException: Could not load default MavensMate settings.\n", "success": false}

[MAVENSMATE]: Calling mm_interface
[MAVENSMATE]: OPERATION: new_project_from_existing_directory
[MAVENSMATE]: {'params': {'directory': '/Users/tgentet-obrien/Dune'}}
[MAVENSMATE]: executing mm terminal call:
[MAVENSMATE]: /Applications/MavensMate.app/Contents/Resources/mm/mm --ui -o new_project_from_existing_directory -c SUBLIME_TEXT_3
[MAVENSMATE]: {"directory": "/Users/tgentet-obrien/Dune"}
[MAVENSMATE]: response from mm: {"body": "Could not load default MavensMate settings.", "stack_trace": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/Users/josephferraro/Development/Github/mm/tools/pyinstaller-dev/mm/build/pyi.darwin/mm/out00-PYZ.pyz/lib.request\", line 63, in execute\n  File \"/Users/josephferraro/Development/Github/mm/tools/pyinstaller-dev/mm/build/pyi.darwin/mm/out00-PYZ.pyz/lib.request\", line 54, in __setup_connection\n  File \"/Users/josephferraro/Development/Github/mm/tools/pyinstaller-dev/mm/build/pyi.darwin/mm/out00-PYZ.pyz/lib.connection\", line 34, in __init__\n  File \"/Users/josephferraro/Development/Github/mm/tools/pyinstaller-dev/mm/build/pyi.darwin/mm/out00-PYZ.pyz/lib.connection\", line 169, in get_plugin_client_settings\nMMException: Could not load default MavensMate settings.\n", "success": false}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 440, in is_enabled_
    ret = self.is_enabled()
  File "/Users/tgentet-obrien/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/MavensMate/mavensmate.py", line 1945, in is_enabled
    fn, ext = os.path.splitext(active_view.file_name())
  File "X/posixpath.py", line 125, in splitext
  File "X/genericpath.py", line 92, in _splitext
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 440, in is_enabled_
    ret = self.is_enabled()
  File "/Users/tgentet-obrien/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/MavensMate/mavensmate.py", line 1945, in is_enabled
    fn, ext = os.path.splitext(active_view.file_name())
  File "X/posixpath.py", line 125, in splitext
  File "X/genericpath.py", line 92, in _splitext
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

The above is the output I am getting when I click on "Create Mavensmate Project..."

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this!

I had a trailing comma in my JSON